# No crank no start 03 gmc yukon

Tags: starting, ignition, gmc, no-crank-no-start, yukon

I have an 03 yukon(5.3L) it wasnt starting a while ago and it just needed a new ignition fuse. After a week of driving it, it didnt want to start again. It has a brand new battery on it and the terminals aren't corroded. All of the related fuses and relays i have checked seem to be functioning. I have also tried to jumpstart it and it didnt help at all. When i insert the key my dash lights dont come on, only the battery indicatior.
It has enough power to turn on my radio and interior lights, but my gauges dont move and my headlights dont turn on either. I have also noticed i dont hear the fuel pump turning on as it normally would when the key is in the acc position. When i turn the key to start it there is no crank no click nothing. This has been nothing but a headache and im just looking for a solution so i dont have to have it towed to a shop.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the actual voltage at the battery?

Comment: The battery dropped just below 12 and i charged it up to around 12.6 and nothing.

Comment: While charging the battery voltage should be around 14V.  So either you have a battery issue or your charging system is bad.

Comment: @jwh20 - You aren't going to see 14vdc charge rate unless the vehicle is running, which the OP specifically states it's not. Typical chargers won't get the battery above 13vdc and even then rarely. Most likely high 12's (ie: 12.8vdc).

Comment: Jumping should work around low battery, bad charging system, to at least get it started if everything is well, but no joy. Then ignition fuse was blown, so something overdraw on it. Smells like a corroded ground or some other electrical issue hopefully not ecu

Comment: I have 2 12” subwoofers and an aftermarket head unit that i believe is drawing too much power and was probably the main cause of this. The ground wasnt corroded on the battery connection but i havent checked anywhere else.

Comment: Even if there is a continuous parasitic draw, jumping should get past it because you are right back to full power essentially. If you use full charge battery/jump and turn to acc and nothing is on, something is either eating all power real time (wires severed, ground corrosion) or the computer is bad. Gonna have to trace it all unfortunately

Comment: @Chris thank you very much. Ill see what i can find out

Comment: 1-the fuel pump doesn't run with Ignition in ACCessory position. EFI/fuel pump turn on when ignition is in ON/RUN. Since the ecm runs with ignition on, not ACC position, the blown ignition fuse would explain why you don't see instrument panel lights. 
2-even presuming your aftermarket sound system was wired correctly, disconnect any/all fuses to either the head unit or amp.
3-try troubleshooting the reason for blowing the ignition fuse since power flows from this fuse to the fuel pump and ecm, I presume either the ecm or bcm drives the instrument panel gauges/indicators.

Comment: @FDryer - While I know the fuel pump doesn't run on an 03 Yukon until KO, in my 18 Silverado, the fuel pump primes when I open the driver's side door. Just mentioning as things they be a changing.

Comment: Just thinking about this ... I'm wondering if the ignition switch itself has gone bad. I don't know directly how you could test it, but a bad one might exhibit what you're describing.

Comment: Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, fuel pump operation upon opening driver's door seems wasteful if opening/closing that door without starting. This is new to me. Perhaps something else is buzzing/humming and not the pump?

Comment: @Tbc - Instead of editing your question to change it, put how you fixed it down as an answer. Then, create a new question and refer back to this question concerning your new issue you've discovered.

Comment: It ended up being the igniton fuse once again , still undetermined what is causing this fuse to continuously blow.